# 501 error when using AJAX on CFC

Tags: jquery, apache, tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have the following form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <label>
        <h1>Input 1</h1>
    </label>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="input_1" class="input">
    </form>
</div>
<!---Javascipt Sources --->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.input').blur(function() {
        var number = $('.input');
        var data = 'number=' + number.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "cfc/form.cfc",
            method: "read",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                if (html == 1) {
                    alert('wyslane');
                }
                else {
                    alert('wrong');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Which points to the following CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="Read" access="remote" output="false">
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I am getting the following error message on the console of Chrome: `"READ http://127.0.0.1:8500/Google%20Drive/testing/cfc/form.cfc 501 (Method READ is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI) "`

Below is the preview page for that call:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 - Error report

## HTTP Status 501 - Method ADDTOSESSION is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI

**type** Status report

**message** Method ADDTOSESSION is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI

**description** The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request (Method ADDTOSESSION is not is not implemented by this servlet for this URI).

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.23

I can hit the CFC fine after I log in to RDS by using the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8500/Google%20Drive/testing/cfc/form.cfc`.

Is there something I did wrong code wise, or is this something funky with the built-in server?  I have also tried it outside of the Google Drive folder, up to the webroot, but I get the same error.  All applicable permissions on the drive itself should be granted (User, Admin, System).

Windows 7 / ColdFusion 10

Answer (score 1):

The CFC method name must be passed as an HTTP parameter (via the `form` or the `url`). Try removing `method: "read"` from your settings and append `?method=read` to your `url` parameter like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "cfc/form.cfc?method=read",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function(html) {
            if (html == 1) {
                alert('wyslane');
            }
            else {
                alert('wrong');
            }
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @imthepitts for pointing me down the correct path.  I copied and pasted your code and got a 500 error.  I modified it a bit to get it to work:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "cfc/form.cfc",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                method: "read",
                input1: 'hi'},
            success: function(html) {
                if (html == 1) {
                    alert('wyslane');
                }
                else {
                    alert('wrong');
                }
            }
     });
```

As a side questions, where would I find out that I have to pass it via the FORM or URL? I seem to keep getting conflicting information as to what to do with AJAX calls and would like some source to reference.  Thank you for you help.

Comment: What was the error you received? Here's a [good explanation of invoking CFCs from the `form` and `url`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7fd9.html).